# Sorting divs with nested content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html

In my application I'm dynamically rendering out images to the client side by side. As a user it's possible to give points to the images, and I want it to be possible to sort the images on points with the highest points first, descending, by clicking a button.

I've seen some examples on Stack regarding sorting divs, but in my example the content that the images should be sorting on is inside some nested divs (se below). What would be a good way of sorting the images on this parameter (points), any ideas?

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="post">
        // other code here
            <img src="img/image1.png" />
        <div class="postDesc">
            // other code here
            <p class="postDescContent">Points: 20</p>
        </div
    </div>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <div class="post">
        // other code here
            <img src="img/image2.png" />
        <div class="postDesc">
            // other code here
            <p class="postDescContent">Points: 10</p>
        </div
    </div>
</div>

// and so on...
```

EDIT: I see that many of you have pointed out the fact that I was using the same id for both imaages. My bad, I know of this and I just forgot it while creating my example. It's changed to classes now instead.

Comment: You should not create multiple elements with same Id. You should keep all divs with class as post inside the one div whose id is image.

Comment: first two ids can't be same dude. I think the Points for the respective images are stored somewhere in Db, So While fetching the image and its corresponding data from Db, you can fetch them in descending or ascending order by using 'Order by'.Then you can take them in a list of objects and show by using ajax dynamically.Everytime if the vote is raise up or down you can call the query again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** ***Take care to avoid duplication of ids***

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="image1">
    <div class="post">
            <img src="img/image1.png" />
        <div class="postDesc">
            <p class="postDescContent">Points: 20</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="image3">
    <div class="post">
            <img src="img/image2.png" />
        <div class="postDesc">
            <p class="postDescContent">Points: 30</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="image2">
    <div class="post">
            <img src="img/image2.png" />
        <div class="postDesc">
            <p class="postDescContent">Points: 10</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var contents = $('div#container div[id^="image"]');
contents.sort(function(a, b) {
    var p1= parseInt($('p.postDescContent', $(a)).text().replace(/Points: /,'').trim()),
        p2 = parseInt($('p.postDescContent', $(b)).text().replace(/Points: /,'').trim());
       return p2  - p1;
});

$('#container').empty().append(contents);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3bXH9/1/)**

Comment: Please read on [how to sort numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) with a compare function

Comment: @Bergi I knew that, but It also do the job and many of my codes are still healthy with this and working. But thanks from heart for you suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the sorting algorithm to other sorting methods. Each of them needs to extract the values-to-sort-by from from the DOM elements, you just will need to change that extraction function. In your case it will be something like

```
parseInt($element.find(".postDescContent").text().replace(/Points: /,""));
```